# Upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: upgrade, 16.10, 17.10

I would like to Install Ubuntu 17.10 on my computer (the latest release). I have an ISO image of Ubuntu 16.10 (non LTS). So can I upgrade from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.10?. Also, considering the fact that the fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10 would mean to install all it's system updates and then further upgrading to 17.10, which is a better option, upgrading or fresh install of 17.10? Also, will upgrading would cost me my data equal to that of the size of the ISO image of Ubuntu 17.10 (i.e, 1.4GB)?

Comment: 16.10 is not supported any more. You won't find a reliable way to upgrade from 16.10. Best would be to get 17.10 iso and do a fresh  installation.

Comment: don't update to 17.10 now. there are to many bugs (libsane broken, copy&paste bug)

Comment: @jms already using 17.10. I'm pretty satisfied apart from some bugs.

Comment: update-manager -cd worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16.10 is no longer supported. Interim (non-LTS) releases are only supported for 9 months. The upgrade path for interim releases, is through the next interim release, so you would need to upgrade to 17.04 and then 17.10.

So yes, if you want 17.10, you should install it directly.

Comment: After installing 17.10, and when the official 18.04 releases, will I be able to update to that?

Comment: Yes, or you can install 16.04 and update directly to 18.04, as it will be an LTS.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I want 17.10 over 16.04 is because I want to experience the new Gnome environment (which now runs natively). :)

Comment: It runs _natively_ in 16.04 too, if you install it. :)

Answer (score 1):

For evaluating new releases, my approach is to partition the boot drive into 3 parts: 1 for ubuntu 16, 1 for ubuntu 17, and 1 for the /home. Easiest way is to use the install routine and choose "other" and related options. Upon restart, choose the version on the boot screen.

[edit]
Since posting this a month prior, Ubuntu 17.10 now enables the "sudo", which permits root and synaptic. hooray!!!  But gnome cannot scale the 4k monitor to 250%, which is not optimum for me, and gnome has other limitations that are suboptimal, not to mention the bugs reported by others. However, since switching from 17.04 unity to 17.10 gnome, I see a definite improvement in overall speed of my desktop. Evince is no longer buggy and slow: it is smooth and quick. Similar for LibreOffice. So gnome is now preferred to unity.